# How to check string in C

Tags: c, string

I am new at C language. In the code below, I am checking if input value is greater than `23` or less than `0`, and if it is, I then ask again for a new value, but now I want to check while any string value come then again ask a new value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int h;

  printf("Value: ");
  scanf("%d", &h);
  while ((h < 0) || (h > 23)) {

    printf("Value: ");
    scanf("%d", &h);

  }
  printf("You pressed:%d\n", h);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I need to check if input like `foo` or any kind of string value than say again value.I mean i need to escape string values in this program.i just need integer value 1 to 23.

Comment: You want read the input until `h` is in a range of `[1,23]`?

Comment: Yas `h` range in 1 to 23 so i don't need string values while string enter than again ask value.

Comment: If you want 1..23, why does your code check for `h < 0` and why does the question say 'greater than 23 or less than 0'?  Computer programming requires precision of thought and expression; sloppy thinking leads to sloppy programming and that leads to bugs.  Don't consider a perpetual supply of bugs you've created as a source of job security.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for suggestion if you can see on top of my question there i first think wrote i am new on C so i am strangling on C language.But ok for best suggestion and also thanks for answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either need to read whole lines using `fgets()` and then scan the line with `sscanf()`, or you need to deal with `scanf()` not being willing to read past a letter when asked to scan for a number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MIN_VALUE = 0, MAX_VALUE = 23 };

int main(void)
{
    int h;
    char line[4096];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
    {
         if (sscanf(line, "%d", &h) == 1 && h >= MIN_VALUE && h <= MAX_VALUE)
         {
             printf("You entered: %d\n", h);
             break;
         }
         printf("What you entered was not a number between %d and %d\n",
                MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you want the acceptable values to be 1..23, change MIN_VALUE to 1.

Note that one advantage of this code using `fgets()` is that you can report what the computer read back to the user — the code doesn't do that, but it could quite easily.  This is most valuable when you're reading multiple values per line.  If the `scanf()` reads 4 of the expected 6 items, you've only got a fragment of the input line to report to the user.  On the other hand, if `sscanf()` reads 4 of the expected 6 items, you can report the whole line that the user entered, which is usually a lot more meaningful to the user.

Or this, perhaps, but it exits on the first non-integer data, which is not really in specification:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int h;
    while (scanf("%d", &h) == 1)
    {
         if (h >= 0 && h <= 23)
         {
             printf("You entered: %d\n", h);
             break;
         }
         printf("What you entered was not a number between 1 and 23\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or maybe you need to gobble the rest of the line of input when the `scanf()` fails:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c, h;
    while (1)
    {
         switch (scanf("%d", &h))
         {
         case EOF:
             return 1;
         case 0:
             printf("What you entered was not a number between 1 and 23\n");
             while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') /* Gobble rest of line */
                 ;
             break;
         default:  /* or case 1: */
             if (h >= 0 && h <= 23)
             {
                 printf("You entered: %d\n", h);
                 return 0;
             }
             break;
         }
    }
    /*NOTREACHED*/
    return 0;
}
```

On second thoughts, use the `fgets()` version; it is cleaner.

Comment: Small correction: The op wants `h` to be a number between `1` and `23`.

Comment: @jonathan Please try to understand my question i need to check string i mean when any string enter than again ask value.

Comment: @user2176127: the question explicitly says _greater than 23 or less than 0_, meaning 0..23 is valid.

Comment: @AffanAhmad: OK; the first and third alternatives do that...the second does not. Of the three, use the first alternative.

Comment: @AffanAhmad Jonathan's code does that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Read the comments. He wants to exclude `h > 23 || h < 0`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler thanks For help and for thumb down.Sound sad

Comment: _@Jonathan Leffler_. Why in your first code `line` size is exactly 4096?

Comment: I use 4096 to avoid most problems with long lines.  A few file types (JSON) tend to have very extremely long lines, but few files formatted with line breaks have lines that long. POSIX suggests 2048; I double that.