# isdigit() in a function

Tags: c, function, parameters

I have a function which takes an integer input by the user.

So I have:

```
scanf("%d, &x);
```

And then, the function:

```
test(int x);
```

Inside test(), I wanna check if the input is a digit or a character, so I tried:

```
if (isdigit(x))
    // piece of code
    printf("Done!\n");
else
    printf("Bye!\n");
```

However, isdigit() does not seem to be working as the program is outputting "Bye!" immediately. What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `isalpha` or `isdigit`?

Comment: Oh, and do you really want to `Scanf` for a *number* if you want to test a character if it's a digit or not?

Comment: Quite a few responders!  Weather must be bad all over.

Comment: @Digital_Reality huh, what? characters are perfectly representable using `int`s.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21058138/971127

Comment: @H2CO3 My bad.. removed..

Comment: Solved! Didn't know isdigit() took char as argument. Thanks guys!

@JoachimPileborg Nah, the scanf() is for user input, the test is in another function preceding the scanf().

And yeah, isdigit(), sry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing integer not char!

`isdigit(x)`  check whether `x` is a digit char  e.g. `'0'`, `'1'`  but not `0`, `1` what you are passing.

It behaves like:

```
 isdigit('h')  returns 0
 isdigit('1')  returns 1      
 isdigit(1)  returns 0    // your are passing this
```

Read [manual](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?isdigit+3):

> Standard C Library Functions                            ctype(3C)
>
> `isdigit()`       Tests for any **decimal-digit character**.

Comment: Oh, dammit, thought it's parameter was int. Thanks! So, all I have to do is isdigit(x) where x is the user input.

Comment: @user3182162 your welcome, Btw change the question title as you got comments from Mr.  Joachim Pileborg

Comment: @user3182162 *`it's parameter was int.`*   in C char constants are int type not char for example `'A'` is int type.

Answer (score 1):

`isdigit` tests a character:

```
isdigit('5') == true;
isdigit(5) == false;
```

Comment: "`isdigit(5) == false`" -- or `true`.

Comment: In fact it return 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

remove the semicolon:

```
if (isdigit(x)); // <===
```

Because of the semicolon, if it is a digit you execute an empty statement.

Comment: Should become a compiler error rather than the else clause is executed if this is the cause then. So this is just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The C library function `void isdigit(int c )` checks if the passed character is a decimal digit character.

The `isdigit() function` returns non-zero if c is a decimal digit otherwise `0`.The input argument is an `int`, the value of which the application shall ensure is a character representable as an `unsigned char` or equal to the value of the macro `EOF`. i.e
ensure that your value is enclosed in single quotes.

You also seemed to have a `;` after the if statement which shifts the expected control flow.

```
char x;  
scanf(" %c", &x); 

if (isdigit(x)) 
  printf("Done!\n");
else 
  printf("Bye!\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Suspect OP wants to read a `char`

```
char x;  // new type
scanf(" %c", &x); // new format specifier

if (isdigit(x))  // remove ;
  // piece of code
  printf("Done!\n");
else if (isalpha(x)) // added test @Joachim Pileborg
  printf("Is a alpha!\n");
else 
  printf("Bye!\n");
```